# Finding Second duplicate element in an array in java

Tags: arrays

**Hi  Everyone, i am new to the programming world, can you  please  help  me in finding second  duplicate element in  an  array. i have tried but its not working.**

public class FindSecondDuplicate {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = { 6,4,2,3,4,6,8};

    int count=0;
    Set<Integer>  set=new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for(int no:intArray)
    {
        if(set.add(no)==false)
        {
            count=count+1;
            if(count==2)
            {
                System.out.println(no);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            set.add(no);
        }
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: This should output ``6``. What is your expected result?

Comment: you are using `set.add(no)` both in `if` condition and `else`statement

Comment: Program's output is 6 which appears to be correct. First repeated is 4 and then 6. What are you expecting?

Comment: yes the output is 6, but  i think  output should be 4

Comment: @Yogeshsolanki can you explain why you think output should be 4?

Comment: @KshitijDhakal , I  was thinking that first element 6 is twice in  the  list and same with  second  element which  is 4 is also repeating, then why not 4.

Comment: @KshitijDhakal dear actually i am newbie may be i am thinking in  another way, please correct it if i wrong,  and  also  please make me understand this logic.

Comment: @Yogeshsolanki there are two ways to look at your problem. First approach is to find duplicate element in the order it appears for first time in array. Second approach is to find duplicate element in the order duplicate element appears in the array. I see that you are trying to do is first case, but your program is doing second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do can be accomplished using

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = {6, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8};
    int count = 0;
    Map<Integer, Integer> repeatCounter = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : intArray) {
        if (repeatCounter.containsKey(i)) {
            int repeatedNTimes = repeatCounter.get(i);
            repeatCounter.put(i, repeatedNTimes + 1);
        }else{
            repeatCounter.put(i, 1);
        }
    }
    for (int i : intArray) {
        if (repeatCounter.get(i) == 2) {
            count++;
            if (count == 2) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find 2nd/3rd or any duplicate with Set Interface

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = {3, 12, 9, 3, 8, 3, 12, 4, 7, 8};
    int find_duplicate = 3;

    // Add all duplicates to set
    Set<Integer> storeDuplicates = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++){
            if (array[i] == array[j]){
                storeDuplicates.add(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Traverse set for find the 2nd/3rd/any other duplicate
    int count = 0;
    for (int i : storeDuplicates){
        count++;
        if (count == find_duplicate) System.out.println(find_duplicate+" duplicate is : "+i);
    }
}
```